# How to escape curly braces in Tcl (f5 bigip cli script)

Tags: command-line-interface, escaping, tcl, f5

Can you help me

Here is the situation

I have a string  similar to this one

```
profile1 { context all } profile2 { context serverside } profile3 { context clientside } profile4 { context clientside } profile5 { context serverside }
```

I  want to change the string  to have each profile with its  context on its own line  like that:

```
profile1 { context all }
profile2 { context serverside }
profile3 { context clientside } 
profile4 { context clientside } 
profile5 { context serverside }
```

I was thinking of  replacing  "} "   with "}\n"     using regsub

```
set modified_profilelist [regsub -all "string_to_replace" $profilelist "replacement_string" ]
```

but I can`t find a way  to escape the curly brace

Anything I try gives me an error

Thanks in advance

Comment: The obvious way would be to write the string_to_replace as "\} " - does that not work?

Comment: How about doing it completely differently: `join [lmap {profile context} $str {list $profile $context}] \n`?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use `string map` to replace the right curly brace + a space with a right curly brace + a new line:

```
set originalString "profile1 { context all } profile2 { context serverside } profile3 { context clientside } profile4 { context clientside } profile5 { context serverside }"
puts "$originalString"
puts "---"
set newString [string map { "\} " "\}\n"}  $originalString]
puts "$newString"
```

Output:

```
profile1 { context all } profile2 { context serverside } profile3 { context clientside } profile4 { context clientside } profile5 { context serverside }
---
profile1 { context all }
profile2 { context serverside }
profile3 { context clientside }
profile4 { context clientside }
profile5 { context serverside }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your real data, like the example, makes a valid tcl list, you can treat it as one, and iterate through two elements at a time:

```
set profiles {profile1 { context all } profile2 { context serverside } profile3 { context clientside } profile4 { context clientside } profile5 { context serverside }}                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
foreach {name value}  $profiles {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    puts [list $name $value]                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl a closing curly bracket has no special meaning without an opening curly bracket before it, so you can safely do the following:

```
regsub -all } $profilelist }\n
```

If you want to use it inside a procedure, then this will also work:

```
regsub -all \} $profilelist \}\n
```